# How to select the max value by condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, iif

I want to select the maximum value if the condition is met, otherwise take all values

```
select debtresidentid, [priority], IIF([priority] = 1, max(phonenum), phonenum) as phonenum
from debtphone
group by debtresidentid, [priority]
```

And I get an error:

> PHONENUM' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I try group by [phonenum] I get all value.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You would phrase this as:

```
select debtresidentid,
       max(case when [priority] = 1 then phonenum end) as phonenum
from debtphone
group by debtresidentid;
```

Note that the SQL standard for conditional logic is `CASE`, not `IIF()`.  I strongly recommend using standard SQL syntax unless you have a good reason for bespoke syntax.

EDIT:

Oh, I think I get it.  You want to return all `priority = 1`.  Otherwise all numbers.  For this, use window functions:

```
select debtresidentid, phonenum
from (select p.*, 
             sum(case when priority = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by debtresidentid) as num_priority_1
      from debtphone p
     ) p
where num_priority_1 > 0 and priority = 1 or
      num_priority_1 = 0
order by debtresidentid;
```

Comment: if '[priority] = 1' i want to return all values